# Support tiff files in android

Tags: android, image

Need to display tiff image as thumbnails in android.These images should be loaded from Url.

Have been searching for options.

Many suggest https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory but then I do not find sources to  decode inputstream.

Other source suggested is https://code.google.com/archive/p/tiffonandroid/ I donot see any source or ussage documents.

Tried to load using Glide, Picasso and Coil but no use.

Please help me to find ways to display tiff images in android.Even if it is paid it is okay.